# Roboframework Selenium - fidn web element and iterate in nested sub-elements

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Hello I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="1234" role="article">
    <div class="A">
        <h2 class="B">
            <a class="C" href="https://www.test.it">
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="X">
        <span class="Y">"some text"
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="1234" role="article">
    <div class="A">
        <h2 class="B">
            <a class="C" href="https://www.test2.it">
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="X">
        <span class="Y">"some text2"
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to iterate in each Div with role=article, and gather corresponding href and text
(i.e. https://www.test.it - "some text" for the first one)

I've created a basic for loop:

```
${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://div[contains(@role, 'article')]
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        Log To Console    ${element.get_attribute('href')}
    END
```

But i cannot figure it out how to get the sub elements that I need.
Any help is more than appreciated.
Many thanks

###Update
this works for the href, but I'm unable to get the span text
${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://div[contains(@role, 'article')]
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
${sub1}=   Set Variable      ${element.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2//a[contains(@class, 'C')]")}
Log To Console    ${sub1.get_attribute('href')}
END

Answer (score -1):

To iterate in each *DIV* with `role="article"` and gather corresponding *href* and *text* you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *href*:

  ```
  ${elements}= Get WebElements xpath://div[contains(@role, 'article')] 
    FOR ${element} IN @{elements} 
        ${sub1}= Set Variable ${element.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2/a[@class='C']")} 
        Log To Console ${sub1.get_attribute('href')} 
    END
  ```
- *text*:

  ```
  ${elements}= Get WebElements xpath://div[contains(@role, 'article')] 
    FOR ${element} IN @{elements} 
        ${sub1}= Set Variable ${element.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='X']/span[@class='Y']")} 
        Log To Console ${sub1.get_attribute('innerHTML')} 
    END
  ```